# Trying to set custom SCM on Capistrano 3.8.1

Tags: ruby, deployment, devops, capistrano3

I am configuring a custom SCM because i don't need the default git in the development local environment, but i would like to trigger a custom logic, mainly based on creating a release starting from a source_directory. 
As described in the documentation (http://capistranorb.com/documentation/advanced-features/custom-scm/) i wrote a module that extends the Capistrano::Plugin, and set required methods to handle the custom SCM implementation used by deploy Capistrano flow.

Besides this, when i put in my config/deploy/`<environment>`.rb the entry:

`set :scm, :<custom plugin name>`

Capistrano keeps to use the default git scm, even if is not declared.

in my Capfile there are loaded both as follow:

```ruby
require_relative 'scm/local.rb'
install_plugin Capistrano::LocalPlugin
require 'capistrano/git
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git
```

Here also the module of custom SCM :

```ruby
 require 'capistrano/scm/plugin'

 module Capistrano
    class Capistrano::SCM::LocalPlugin < ::Capistrano::Plugin
       def set_defaults
        set_if_empty :source_dir, 'non-exisisting-dir'
       end

    def define_tasks
        namespace :local do
          task :create_release do
              run_locally do
                  execute :mkdir, '-p', :'tmp'
                  execute "cd #{fetch(:source_dir)} && tar -cz --exclude tests --exclude vendor --exclude .git --exclude node_modules --exclude tmp/#{fetch(:release_timestamp)}.tar.gz -f tmp/#{fetch(:release_timestamp)}.tar.gz ."
              end

              on release_roles :all do
                  execute :mkdir, '-p', release_path
                  upload! "tmp/#{fetch(:release_timestamp)}.tar.gz", "#{release_path}/#{fetch(:release_timestamp)}.tar.gz"
                  execute "tar -xvf #{release_path}/#{fetch(:release_timestamp)}.tar.gz --directory #{release_path}"
                  execute "rm #{release_path}/#{fetch(:release_timestamp)}.tar.gz"
              end

              run_locally do
                  execute "rm -rf tmp"
              end
          end

          desc 'Determine the revision that will be deployed'
          task :set_current_revision do
              run_locally do
                  set :current_revision, capture(:git, " --git-dir #{fetch(:source_dir)}/.git rev-parse --short #{fetch(:branch)}")
              end
          end
        end
    end

    def register_hooks
        after 'deploy:new_release_path', 'local:create_release'
    end
end
```

end

Does anyone know which is the black magic to use in order to say to Capistrano to use my scm instead of the default git one ?

Comment: If i comment the `install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::git`,  the custom scm will be loaded. But obviously i would like to choose which one use, only by setting the `set :scm, <custom scm>` property in the right config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set :scm, 'myscm'` [is deprecated](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/7ba6e446ff4f517814d8e5a79710aa122a8b9064/lib/capistrano/configuration/scm_resolver.rb#L7). Until the next major version of Capistrano (4.0), [there is a class](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/7ba6e446ff4f517814d8e5a79710aa122a8b9064/lib/capistrano/configuration/scm_resolver.rb#L7) which checks for an SCM having been installed via `install_plugin`, and if not, checks for the `set :scm` definition. If `install_plugin` has been called, then `set :scm` is ignored and deleted.

`install_plugin` only registers the plugin. It looks to me [from the code](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/configuration/plugin_installer.rb#L24) that Capistrano will run both plugins if two are installed.

So, in a nutshell, Capistrano doesn't support selecting multiple SCMs based on environment. The closest thing to that you could try is using an environment variable to conditionally load the SCM in your Capfile. Something like:

```
if ENV['CAP_SCM'] == 'local'
  require_relative 'scm/local.rb'
  install_plugin Capistrano::LocalPlugin
else
  require 'capistrano/git'
  install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git
end
```

This is all documented here: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/UPGRADING-3.7.md